# Running different JS for IE6/Other browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, compatibility

I have some code:

```
document.getElementById("gD" + gDay + gMonth + gYear).setAttribute("class", "gDay gDayHover");
```

This works in all modern browsers but not IE6.  IE6 needs:

```
document.getElementById("gD" + gDay + gMonth + gYear).setAttribute("className", "gDay gDayHover");
```

I'm going to have another variable:

```
var addOnClassAtt;
```

which is either set to "" or "Name" so I can run the single line:

```
document.getElementById("gD" + gDay + gMonth + gYear).setAttribute("class" + addOnClassAtt, "gDay gDayHover");
```

How would I determine if the user is running a browser that requires className and not class?  I'd rather steer away from browser detection and have an initial try catch type method to set this, but if this is not possible what is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, you're better off doing feature detection rather than browser detection. Feature detection is both easier and more reliable in Javascript than browser detection.

In this particular instance, you'd be better off setting the class like this:

```
document.getElementById(...).className = "gDay gDayHover";
```

This code should work in all browsers, including IE6.

The reason you've had a problem with this one is that the class attribute is referred to as `className` in the DOM.

This is because the word `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript, so having it in the DOM could cause ambiguity in some cases, but as you see, the solution to that problem ended up causing other problems!

The lesson to take from this is that `setAttribute` is not a reliable function to use for setting the `class` attribute. Most other attributes should be fine with `setAttribute`, though a few others may also have issues, so in general its best to use the DOM property.

Comment: Not entirely true: `for` is also problematic, for the same reason. In general, always use DOM element's properties instead of `setAttribute`.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel - thank you. I've edited the last part of my answer to clarify what I meant and to include your point.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `setAttribute` to set a class name, IE will freak out; instead set the *property* `className` of the DOM object:

```
document.getElementById("gD" + gDay + gMonth + gYear).className = "gDay gDayHover";
```

Comment: Perfect solution thank you!  Seems to work in all browsers as well.

Comment: Are you sure IE6 supports multiple classes in className?

Comment: @kennebec: Yeah, why shouldn't it? Just tested this and it worked as expected.